# Qt cross-compiler for armhf

Tags: c++, qt, arm, debian

I have to install and configure Qt on my virtual machine, I crossed a few steps in that installation, but I get stuck in situation when I need to add appropriate qmake file. I installed qt4-qmake and qt5-qmake in the hope that they will be located in /usr/bin and I thought that those files need to be added to Build & Run -> Qt Versions

When trying to add qmake (qt5-qmake) I get error "The qmake executable could not be added..."

When I add qmake-qt4 it tells me that my Qt version is invalid, here is the picture

[image]

What else should I try? Install older version of Qt? Where to find it?

I installed Qt via qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.5.1.run on my Debian 32bit virtual machine.

Comment: you should select the `qmake` from your `Qt` installation directory which is by default `/opt/QtXX` if you ran the installer as root, else `/home/user/QtXX`. `qmake` is located in `bin` folder inside `Qt` directory.

Comment: Thats not qmake file for armhf but for x86

Comment: cross compiling isn't as simple as selecting a `qmake`. You must have the target rootfs configured i.e., `Qt` for your target should already be there.

Comment: What board are you targeting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download a complete installation of Qt that is built for armhf and compatible with your system. That installation should contain also a qmake binary built for x86 or x64, depends on your platform. Once you select that, you'll also have to select the proper crosscompiler and set it in the "Compilers" tab you see in the shot. Then, you'll have to associated crosscompiler and Qt build in a complete Kit in the "Kit" tab you see there in Qt Creator. You'll also have to set a proper sysroot, containing all the libs from your arm system.

The other option, as suggested by others, is to build on your own. It is probably the best option as Qt depends on many other system components and the build must be compatible with that.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install a Qt compiled for armhf (not x86 as you did, apt sources files are generally build for the own architecture). This will include an armhf-build qmake.

As an alternative you can download the source, setup a cross-compiler armhf build-chain (g++ for armhf) and compile qt by yourself.

Advantage of a complete package (Qt for Android for example) is you already get the complete armhf build-chain including the timeconsuming build shared libraries